# Datos no se estan actualizando en la base de datos

Tags: sql-server, nodejs, base-de-datos

Estoy tratando de actualizer datos en la base de datos, utilizando un API con el metodo put,

Anexo codigo

API

```
router.put("/updatingUser", (req, res) =>{
   
   const user = new UserObject(req.body.Id,
      req.body.nombre,
      req.body.apellidoPaterno,
      req.body.apellidoMaterno,
      req.body.edad,
      req.body.email)
    dbOperations.updateUsers(id,
     user.gettingNombre(), 
     user.gettingApellidoPaterno(), 
     user.gettingApellidoMaterno(), 
     user.gettingEdad(), 
     user.gettingEmail()).then(result =>{
      res.json(result)
     })
})
```

Operacion en base de datos

```
async function updateUsers(
  id,
  nombre,
  apellidoPaterno,
  apellidoMaterno,
  edad,
  email
) {
  try {
    console.log(id, nombre, apellidoPaterno, apellidoMaterno, edad, email)
    let pool = await sql.connect(config);
    const consult = await pool.request().query(`UPDATE usersAPI
    SET nombre = ${nombre}, 
      apellidoPaterno = ${apellidoPaterno},
      apellidoMaterno = ${apellidoMaterno},
      edad = ${edad},
      email = ${email}
      where id = ${id}
         `);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Pero me esta saliendo el siguiente error:     RequestError: Invalid column name 'adrtyf'.

estos son los datos que estoy mando por postman

```
{
    "Id": "1",
    "nombre": "jose",
    "apellidoPaterno": "mandez",
    "apellidoMaterno": "adrtyf",
    "edad": "89",
    "email": "oojojo@outlook.com"
}
```

Ya que estoy estudiando

1. Lo estoy haciendo de la manera correcta?
2. porque me sale este error?

espero me puedan ayudar!!

muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Holaa!! ya encontre la respuesta,

El problema era en

```
SET nombre = ${nombre}, 
      apellidoPaterno = ${apellidoPaterno},
      apellidoMaterno = ${apellidoMaterno},
      edad = ${edad},
      email = ${email}
      where id = ${id}
```

cuando estaba hacienda la actualizacion y estaba pasando el argumento como ${}, que sera lo que pasaba?

1. SQL SERVER estaba tomando los valores como nombre de tablas en vez de tomarlos como valores, asi que la solucion fue la siguiente:

   ***let pool = await sql.connect(config)
   const result = await pool.request()
   .input("userId", sql.Int, userId)
   .input("name", sql.NVarChar, name)
   .input("lastName", sql.NVarChar, lastName)
   .input("middleName", sql.NVarChar, middleName)
   .input("age", sql.Int, age)
   .input("email", sql.NVarChar, email)
   .query(`UPDATE usersAPI SET nombre = @name, apellidoPaterno = @lastName, apellidoMaterno = @middleName, edad = @age, email = @email where id = @userId`
   );***

estaba poniendo los valores directo en vez de utilizar valores con paramentros utilizando
.input("userId", sql.Int, userId

y en la consulta llamar al parametron con @parametro

Saludos!!